# Device Rotation causing Activity to be destroyed and created

Tags: java, android

I know that Android destroys the current activity and recreates it back because of the device configuration has changed during runtime.

But what is the rationale behind in designing such behaviour ?.

I mean why should the current activity be destroyed and recreated.
Is there any drawback if it does not happen like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what is the rationale behind in designing such behaviour ?

Configuration changes often mean that you need different resources:

- Different strings for locale changes
- Different layouts for orientation changes
- Different graphics for night mode versus day mode
- Etc.

Android does not have a way to replace all your resource uses, except by forcing you to reload them all.

> Is there any drawback if it does not happen like that ?

The drawback is that developers will screw it up.

- They will prevent activities from being destroyed and recreated for some configuration changes but not others, and therefore their app breaks when those other configuration changes occur. So, for example, the app might break when the user puts the device in a desk dock, because the developer added `android:configChanges=screenSize|orientation` to the manifest and completely ignored other configuration change scenarios.
- They will miss resources. For example, "just add to manifest android:configChanges=screenSize|orientation into activity tag" will not actually fix the UI to take screen orientation into account, and so the UI might be cut off at the bottom. Or, the developer forgot to reload *every* string resource, and so now with a locale change the UI has a mixed set of languages. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's see [what Google has to say about it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html):

> The restart behavior is designed to help your application adapt to new configurations by automatically reloading your application with alternative resources that match the new device configuration.

So what does that mean? The Android designers decided that (most*) well-designed apps should have resources tailored to different configurations. For instance, most apps have a different layout for portrait and landscape modes. Not only that, but things like language changes may need different strings, etc.

To handle this, there are one of (at least)two ways you can do it. Restart the whole thing, or just load new resources.

To load just the new resources would put an extra burden on developers(IMO), by forcing them to think more deeply about exactly which resources are needed, and make them all reload in some sort of `onConfigChanged()` method. What happens if you miss one? What if you don't load them in the same sequence as you did before? Will that change things?

By restarting the entire process, it ensures you are starting from a blank slate, and the app should respond exactly the way it would if you had started from that configuration in the first place(which you technically did).

---

*Of course there are exceptions to the rule. Any app that is locked into one orientation, for example, isn't concerned with orientation changes. Some enterprise apps don't need multiple languages, etc. The goal is to make it easy for the 90%, not the 10%.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind that lifecycle flow is that android provides mechanisms to use specific resources based on the devices configuration.

If you, for example, wanted to use one layout file in portrait mode, and a different layout file in landscape, an activity that was instantiated using the portrait mode won't have access to the landscaped file unless it goes through the process to recreate itself. You then design your UI controller (be it activity, or fragment) to inflate the right views and use certain rendering logic based on the configuration. Android provides hooks for you to save data or state that was loaded in one configuration and then reload it when the configuration changes.

95% of the time, most apps/developers don't use this pattern, and it ends up making your code a bit more verbose in terms of having to save the state of objects on configuration changes but android also provides a mechanism to handle that for you.

[Fragment#setRetainInstance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) is a mechanism for you to store the state of the UI or data in a fragment, and when the activity rotates, it will use the same fragment on rotation. The patterns goes like so

```
//in onCreate in your activity
Fragment myFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT_TAG");
if(myFrag == null) {
    myFrag = new MyFragment();
    myFrag.setRetainInstanceState(true);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
        .replace(android.R.id.content, myFrag, "MY_FRAGMENT_TAG");
        .commit();
}
```

When the activity runs its onCreate again, it will call the findFragmentByTag and it will not be null and the old fragment will still be attached to the UI

Answer (score -1):

just add to manifest android:configChanges=screenSize|orientation into activity tag

Comment: First, it does not solve the problem, as there are many other configuration changes beyond those. Second, few applications need *zero* changes on an orientation change, and so usually there is more work than "just add to manifest".